# GCC doesn't compile with libraries installed to a virtual environment

Tags: python, c, opencv, raspberry-pi, cython

I have a problem with compiling using GCC toolchain. I'm working on facial detection program using OpenCV destined to work later in an Embedded Linux platform such as Raspberry PI3, this is how I proceed:

***First, on a PC running Ubuntu:***

In this machine I installed OpenCV 2.4 with **NO** virtual environnment.

I developed the software in Python 2.7, using OpenCV library and other libraries such as NumPy and others. Now to optimize my code I use Cython to convert the .py files to .c then I compile and link the resulted .c files into a unique executable file. The executable works fine and passes all the tests, I also gain in performance (quick response).

***Second, on Raspberry PI 3 the problem occurs***

Here I have installed OpenCV 3.1.0 IN A VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT called (cv) with Python 2.7.

Then I try to port the code source to Raspberry PI after some tweaking and some minor modifications i get my Python files .py working and the software works fine. Now the problem is that when I procedd with the same method to compile the .C files generated using Cython, the compilation fails, I guess because of the fact that OpenCV was installed only in the virtual environment, so I gave GCC a link to the path of the VirtualEnv folder where OpenCV is installed and the compilation passes. But the executable still gives me an error saying that Import cv2 fails to find the cv2 package even if all thses steps are done with the (cv) virtual environment activated.

Now I have to questions:
- Is there any method to generalize what has been installed in a virtual environment, I mean for example in my case, that i need OpenCV to be callable from anywhere in the Raspberry without logging to the virtual environment?
- Are executables aware of the fact that they are launched on a virtual environment? I mean if they need a package that is only installed in a virtual env, how could I make them know that ?

**NB** I based my methods on these two articles:

- [Install guide: Raspberry Pi 3 + Raspbian Jessie + OpenCV 3](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/)
- [Fast, optimized ‘for’ pixel loops with OpenCV and Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/08/28/fast-optimized-for-pixel-loops-with-opencv-and-python/)

Comment: Add the OpenCV directory to `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables.

Comment: @zindarod What directory should I add exactly? I added the dist-packages directory : `/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` where the cv2.so  is installed to both variablesbut it's still doesn't work !

Answer (score 1):

To activate the virtualenv for all processes the following environment variables need to be set.

```
VIRTUAL_ENV=<absolute path of virtual env directory>
PATH=<virtual env dir>/bin:$PATH
```

You can set these on boot in the usual places (`/etc/profile` et al) to make all processes use the virtual env by default.

Comment: I verified the variables contain already that. The problems is that the executable doesn't detected the cv2 (says: 
`ImportError: No module named cv2`
Even when I launch the executable from within the virtual environment! But when I launch a normal python script it works normally!

Comment: If cv2 does not work in the virtualenv then how do you expect enabling virtualenv to make a difference? Fix the installation in the virtualenv then it will work.

Comment: I said that CV2 works great when I run the Python script in the virtualenv, the problem appears when i run the executable, when i run it it gives me that error even if i run it inside the virtualenv u see what i mean?